# Troubles with making a custom template for posts

Tags: custom-post-types, page-template

Is it possible to make a template for all posts in a custom post type? For example I would like to be able to change an adsense ad or some other element on every post by simply editing a custom template.

I have been experimenting with templates that are pretty static, but I am stumped on which one to copy/edit for the posts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it possible, take a look at [**Template Hierarchy codex entry**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) to get a better idea but the simple answer is to create a template for all of you custom post type posts
create a template and name it `single-{post_type}.php` so if your post type is named dogs then your template file should be named `single-dogs.php` and automatically this template file will be used to display all of the dogs post type posts and once you edit that file it will effect all of the posts of that type.

Comment: Wow fantastic... that was fast :D  It's amazing how much information is in the Codex, and yet I consistently fail at finding it :)

Answer (score 0):

This image is invaluable; make sure you print it out and keep it around your desk:

http://codex.wordpress.org/images/thumb/1/18/Template_Hierarchy.png/750px-Template_Hierarchy.png